# Changing values in a list with a click

Tags: python, list, counter

I'm working on a 'card game'. The idea is that when the user can reveal up to two cards at the same time, so when they click on a third card, the previous two disappear. Later I will modify the code, so that if the cards the user clicked on were the same, they'd stay exposed.

The problem is that right now only one card gets exposed. When I click on another card, the first one turns back face down.

Here's the function, why does it not work?

```
def mouseclick(pos):
    global exposed, click_count, turn
    # add game state logic here
    for card in range(len(deck)):
        if pos[0] > card * w and pos[0] < card * w + w:
            exposed[card] = True
            click_count += 1
            if click_count > 2:
                click_count = 1
                turn += 1
            print click_count
        else: 
            exposed[card] = False
        if exposed[card] == True:
            pass
    print exposed
```

BTW, the code won't work unless you run it in CodeSkulptor:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_BGhWSBJ6ln_0.py

```
# implementation of card game - Memory

import simplegui
import random

deck = range(0, 8)* 2
exposed = [False] * len(deck)
print exposed
print deck
w = 50
h = 100
WIDTH = w * 16 + 2
HEIGHT = 102
click_count = 0
turn = 0
# helper function to initialize globals
def new_game():
    global exposed, click_count
    random.shuffle(deck)
    exposed = [False] * len(deck)
    click_count = 0
    print deck
    print exposed


# event handlers
def mouseclick(pos):
    global exposed, click_count, turn
    # add game state logic here
    for card in range(len(deck)):
        if pos[0] > card * w and pos[0] < card * w + w:
            exposed[card] = True
            click_count += 1
            if click_count > 2:
                click_count = 1
                turn += 1
            print click_count
        else: 
            exposed[card] = False
        if exposed[card] == True:
            pass
    print exposed


# cards are 50x100 pixels in size    
def draw(canvas):
    line = 1
    x = 1
    y = 1
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        if exposed[i] == True:
            canvas.draw_text(str(deck[i]), [(0.3* w) + w * i, (y + h) * 0.66], 40, "Black")
        else:
            canvas.draw_polygon([[x, y], [x + w, y], [x + w, y + h], [x, y + h]], line, "White", '#55aa55')
        x += w



# create frame and button and labels
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Memory", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
frame.add_button("Reset", new_game)
label = frame.add_label("Turns = " + str(turn))
frame.set_canvas_background("White")
# register event handlers
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(mouseclick)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# get things rolling
new_game()
frame.start()
```

Comment: the mistake is on `else: exposed[card] = False`. You set it to False so it turns around again. Generally the `for` loop in the `mouseclick` function is not the best. Simplify your logic. Streamline your `if` statements

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are logically wrong. If you want to exposed two card and disappear then when clicked in third one, you can not use only boolean True and False.
Use a list or Two variable for first two action, If action is more then two then clear all and save third action.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what I found so far based on your code.
First of all yes it is possible. I created a second list which is a copy of exposed list. I update it right below where you update the exposed[card].
What I realized is that it keeps a second value True, even when exposed keeps just one. [1st attempt to remove the bug](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_BGhWSBJ6ln_2.py)

I have included some print statements with the changes made. I know, it's not much nor an exact solution, but I don't have any more time to work with it. Keep the question active and I will get back with it ASAP.